# link to boost::thread fails

Tags: c++, boost, cmake, linker-errors

I'm trying to install a program called mgiza. It compiles with CMake and requires some boost libraries.
I used the commands

```
cmake .
make
```

When I run 'make' I get the following errors:

```
d4norm.cxx:(.text+0x95b): undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()'
```

and the likes. I inserted the following line in cmakelists.txt:

```
FIND_PACKAGE( Boost 1.41 COMPONENTS system)
```

it worked because more files could be compiled and the warning above disappeared, but I got another warnings:

```
main.cpp:(.text+0x7174): undefined reference to `boost::thread::hardware_concurrency()'
```

although I already have the FIND_PACKAGE( Boost 1.41 COMPONENTS thread) in the cmakelists.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Shouldn't those be on a single line: `FIND_PACKAGE( Boost 1.41 COMPONENTS system thread)`? Otherwise the latter line will overwrite the variables set by the former.

Answer (score 4):

You also need to search for the thread component:

```
find_package(Boost 1.41 COMPONENTS thread system)
```

In newer versions of Boost.Thread you also should link against Boost.Chrono

```
find_package(Boost COMPONENTS thread chrono system)
```

Then you also need to link your executable against it and add the includes:

```
# Check if everything worked out
if(Boost_FOUND)
  add_executable(main main.cpp) # your executable or library or whatever
  target_link_libraries(main ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
  target_include_directories(main ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})
else()
  # panic
endif()
```

Comment: Done, but it threw 'target_include_directories called with incorrect number of arguments'

Comment: Then it might not be finding the specified libraries. Check the value of `BOOST_THREAD_FOUND` etc.

Comment: Going by [the docs](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/module/FindBoost.html), I've changed `BOOST_LIBRARIES` to `Boost_LIBRARIES`.

Comment: I wonder if the order they're listed in the `find_package` on Linux matters too?  If they get linked in the same order as they're found, probably the order in the `find_package` command should be `thread chrono system`?

Comment: I added the parameter PUBLIC to target_include_directories just to match the param number, it worked, but then I got some other reference errors to header files. I can't get this to work... I'll look for the binaries I need instead. Thanks for your help

Comment: @Fraser Thanks for the edit. The order is very likely to be important and the order I gave is probably wrong. For this is reason I tend to create IMPORTED targets for all boost-subcomponents and fix up their dependencies manually.

Comment: @ViktorPless Look at Fraser's edit to the answer and also fix the order in which the libraries are searched. I'll edit this in.

Comment: @pmr Yes - we've had a merry old time trying to integrate boost with our project cleanly!  We've ended up with a fairly complex combination of `ExternalProject` calls (which does the download, extract and builds bjam as part of the configure step) and `add_library(... IMPORTED ...)` calls.  It works OK for us now on all the platforms we support, but I'd love for the next stage of Boost's development (after the recent huge modularisation effort) to be the change to CMake.  Our code for this is [here](https://github.com/maidsafe/MaidSafe/blob/master/cmake_modules/add_boost.cmake) by the way.

Comment: @Fraser This is strictly off-topic now: Have you tried boost-cmake and imported targets? If you already go through the trouble of using `ExternalProject` that could simplify things a lot.

Comment: @pmr Yes - a long time back.  It didn't work out for us: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18354398/what-is-the-best-way-to-build-boost-with-cmake