# CMake + Boost in Windows, total complete utter dead end no matter what

Tags: c++, windows, boost, cmake

First off, I can make it work in the trivial case of literally hard-coding boost’s path in the CMakeLists.txt, as long as I just append it to the includes, and don’t say a word about the existence of something called “Boost”. The entire reason I’m trying to use CMake, though, is so that I can have a build system that assumes absolutely nothing whatsoever about the system the build takes place in (at least for libraries that have a CMake-included Find*.cmake. Seriously, I’ll figure out how to write modules for obscure 3rd party libraries, but this is *boost* we’re talking about).

The moment I start talking about anything called “Boost”, FindBoost.cmake fails miserably no matter what I do to help it along (apart from editing it or adding system-specific info to my build). `find_package(Boost REQUIRED)` even fails when I set the environment variable `Boost_INCLUDE_DIR` (I tried “`/development_resources/boost_1_55_0`”, “`C:/development_resources/boost_1_55_0`”, “`C:\\development_resources\\boost_1_55_0`”, and “`C:\development_resources\boost_1_55_0`”) and clear CMake’s cache. I’ve tried moving it from my custom folder to both “Program Files” and “Program Files (x86)” (figuring perhaps FindBoost.cmake tried these ‘default locations’).

And then, even *when* I give up (temporarily, for experimental purposes) and put `set(BOOST_ROOT /development_resources/boost_1_55_0)`, then `find_package(Boost COMPONENTS rational REQUIRED)` insists it can’t find required libraries for header-only libraries. If you’re telling my I have to compile boost *anyway*, there’s something seriously wrong. It is totally inconceivable in my mind that that could be the solution. That, and I *think* I had it compiled at one point anyway (*maybe*), but I’ve clean-slated boost on my system since, to try to flush out some of the troubles I was having. It’s possible I have not had it compiled at the same time as having told CMake where to find it properly. I don’t even know.

CMake isn’t looking very promising.

Comment: This is a pretty confused question, spiced with a lot of irrelevant information. Did you check the Q&A in the **Related** section at the down right side of your question?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the best way to build boost with cmake?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18354398/what-is-the-best-way-to-build-boost-with-cmake)

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: no, it's not a duplicate of that question--this one is trying to use CMake to build programs that depend on Boost.  That one is trying to use CMake to build Boost itself from Boost sources.

Comment: FindBoost looks for boost in the standard library paths, for the cygwin environment (which I'm assuming you're using). There is a list of additional paths to look in, you'll have to add your obviously custom boost path that list.

Comment: And the question is ...?

Comment: There is no questions..., but it sounds like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/a/6646746/417197

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you add boost libraries in CMakeLists.txt](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6646405/how-do-you-add-boost-libraries-in-cmakelists-txt)