# What is the relationship between use of `git submodules` and `ExternalProject_Add` for dependency mangement in CMake?

Tags: c++, git, cmake, git-submodules, external-project

I've spent a lot of time recently following a long gone developer's vague and incorrect build instructions for a C++ project I'm working on. Therefore, I'm writing a new build system and I'm looking for the best way to do it. I've settled on using the `ExternalProject_Add` command in CMake for collecting and building dependencies before the project targets but I've also found an excellant [article](https://blog.kitware.com/cmake-superbuilds-git-submodules/) suggesting use of git submodules, which looks like it does a very similar, if not the same thing. So my question: What is the relationship between [git submodules](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/GitSubmodules/article.html) and [ExternalProject_Add](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/ExternalProject.html)?

Comment: `git submodules` is provided by `git` utility, `ExternalProject_Add` is provided by CMake. How they could be "the **same thing**"? Do you want to **compare** these functionalities as a way for handle **external dependencies** in a CMake project? I am unsure that prop. and cons. request is on-topic on Stack Overflow and can be properly answered. BTW, instead of `ExternalProject_Add` it is `FetchContent` functionality which is similar to one provided by `git submodules`. It is mainly up to the project's developer to choose one of `FetchContent` or `git submodules`.

Comment: "the same thing", I mean in terms of functionality. I didn't mean to imply they are exact. It seems to me they both enable third party libraries to be intstalled without much hastle. I want to know what the 'normal' (for want of a better word) C++ developer knows about these two similar features. Perhaps your right, this is boarding on being off-topic for stack overflow, but I'd still find it very useful to have an answer however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ExternalProject_Add` without git submodules:

```
if (SPECIAL_CASE)
  include (ExternalProject)
  ExternalProject_Add (
    project1
    PREFIX project1
    GIT_REPOSITORY "https://github.com/project.git"
    GIT_TAG "v1"
  )
endif ()
```

`project` will be cloned to `CURRENT_BINARY_DIR`, built and installed into local system before main project build. Your main project will use `#include <project/header.h>` from global scope. This solution is suitable for **popular projects** only, that are available as dependency for part of target operating systems. You can guarantee that your target system will receive required version of dependency.

For example lets look at [`openssl`](https://github.com/openssl/openssl), your local system 100% have this library installed. Your target operating systems list includes native `Win32` (without `MinGW` or `CygWin`). All available releases of `openssl` for `Win32` are too ancient, you won't be able to find required version of `openssl` installer for `Win32`. So you may use `#include <openssl/ssl.h>` together with `if (WIN32) ExternalProject_Add` without submodule. There is no point in adding `openssl` submodule to your project.

Please review the [following example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24508888/when-does-externalproject-add-build).

If external `project` is not popular, not available in popular package managers (as rpm, deb, ebuilds, etc) than it is better to use submodules.