# How to build boost log v2 with cmake?

Tags: c++, boost, cmake, boost-log

It seems that most users will just use a pre build version of boost in combination with `find_package`.

I always download my 3rd party dependencies via git and integrate them in cmake. This was usually not a problem because all my libraries were either using cmake or were just header only libraries.

How would I integrate [boost log](https://github.com/boostorg/log) into my cmake build system? Do I need to treat it as if I had written it myself and compile it manually by including every .h and .cpp files and build it as a shared library?

Or is there a more simple way, for example reusing the `.jam` file in cmake?

Comment: Look at ExternalProject_Add https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.4/module/ExternalProject.html

Comment: Good question. I hate bjam, and if somebody was able to create a sane build system for boost, that would be fantastic.

Comment: Do the CMake ports still exist? I followed these a few years ago but once I got bjam working in my CMake generated build scripts I have not worried about it since it has not caused my much issue. Edit: Looks like these are several years old http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18354398/what-is-the-best-way-to-build-boost-with-cmake

Comment: From my last link this answer uses ExternalProject_add to download and build boost: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18357815/487892