# Is there a way to build boost library when my project is built?

Tags: boost, socket.io, cmake

I'm new at boost library.

I have question if it is possible to build boost library right before my visual studio project is built(using something like prebuild script)

More specifically, my project is using socket.io-client-cpp. it uses boost library and demands to install boost before build for itself. It's so so so annoying to novice like me. So I want to automate that process. I think using cmake can be the solution maybe.

Comment: Can you please give more details on what you have already tried and why it didn't fit your needs? Examples can be found e.g. [here](https://github.com/Orphis/boost-cmake) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18354398/is-there-a-maintained-up-to-date-cmake-based-build-for-boost).

Answer (score 0):

[https://sourceforge.net/projects/boost/?source=directory][1]
download the windows version boost.